# Zener diode over capacitor to ground on PCB for PV module

Tags: capacitor, diodes

For a school project, we are required to open a PV module and examine its circuitry to understand how the module functions. At the DC input side, which is powered by the PV string, we have Cy capacitors for both the positive and negative wires leading to the ground, with Zener diodes placed across them. A similar circuit was also discovered at the output (AC side) for each line. What is the purpose of such a circuit, and why is it present both at the input and output?

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. By AC side, does the panel come with a microinverter?